# Indicate what level an overridden setting comes from

Tags: settings

For reports my team releases, we have a hierarchy like this.

[image: Report object settings hierarchy]

Customer administrators aren't allowed to modify the base settings, but they can set overrides one level below. Copies of the report can then be created which further allow settings to be overridden. When working with a copy of the report, users see a screen similar to this.

[image: User report settings]

The first column of values indicates the currently applicable value, from either the base settings or the customer overrides. The second column allows users to enter in their override values.

We'd like to modify this form to give some indication of where the active value is coming from, the base settings or the customer overrides. What's the best way to do that without introducing a lot of clutter into an already cramped form?

Comment: Give more context - what is the type of report you are talking about, in what domain. Give more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine of two possibilities:

- you could show a little icon before each value indicating if its an override or not
- or, depending on how the overrides are created, you could show the original values in a disabled text box and give the user an option to create an override (for example by providing a check-box next to the value or by providing a "add override" button for the whole form)

So basically from my point of view it depends a lot on how the overrides are done by the users.

By example: if you edit multiple objects in AD-explorer in Windows Server you have to explicitly set a checkbox for each value that you would like to set for all objects (not exactly the same use case but nearly the same UI)

Answer (score 2):

A simple inline badge doesn't take up that much room and would be easier to understand than icon or just directly using color. This allows you to scale should you have a very deep inheritance model.

Also because the "Value" is inherited, you might want to show it as regular text to emphasize what the user can edit.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM3P72.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Hopefully the hierarchy won't get any more complicated than it is now, but I like the idea combining this with sc911's answer and designing icons to call out multiple levels, rather than just overridden/not.

Answer (score 0):

The approach described by sc911 is certainly worth considering.

Another option would be to just make use of colour as an indicator. Below is a quick mock-up I did to show one way you could do this:

[image]

Of course, the colours you use will depend on your overall design and scenario, but you get the idea.